# How can I turn of CSRF protection globally on Symfony 3 with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, csrf

I am having a sessions issue that results "Failed to start the session: already started by PHP.". As a temporary workaround, I wan't to disable CSRF protection globally, including FOSUserBundle. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this available at [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#csrf-protection) :

```
framework:
    csrf_protection:
        enabled:   false
```

and if you need to disable it also in login form you just go to your security.yml file and remove the csrf_provider from the form_login directive, don't need to update the action class or anything.